# How to transform datetime (example: 2015/06/04 22:31:25) to January, 4, 2015

Tags: php, datetime

I want to transform datetime (example: 2015/06/04 22:31:25) to **January, 4, 2015**/**Jan, 4, 2015** in php, it's possibly?

It's like in Stackoverflow...

Another example:
**answered Apr 11 at 14:33**

Now I did think... this COULD be made with **preg_replace**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you perchance had a look at [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime)? And no, regex is in no way the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the following should work using DateTime.

Single Line (just to be like the rest)

```
echo date_create('2015/06/04 22:31:25')->format('F j, Y');
```

Cleaner Version (imo)

```
$date = new DateTime('2015/06/04 22:31:25');
echo $date->format('F j, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant June 4, not January 4. The quick way is [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with strtotime. Of course, DateTime is the *proper* way, but here is an example of one way to do it:

```
echo date('F j, Y',strtotime('2015/06/04 22:31:25')) . " / " . date('M j, Y',strtotime('2015/06/04 22:31:25'));
```

If this doesn't work, PHP might be getting confused about the date format since it makes certain assumptions. In this case, try the following option:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d G:i:s','2015/06/04 22:31:25');
echo $date->format("F j, Y") . " / " . $date->format("M j, Y");
```

Comment: Year is failed, this has been the result: June 5, 6722

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date()` function in php . In your case to can do it like this :

```
echo date ("F j, Y  g:i a",strtotime(yourvariableHere));
```

The result of this is : `June 4, 2015 10:00 am`

For more information about date format and time you can visit this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library. It has amazing functionality.

```
echo Carbon::parse('2015/06/04 22:31:25')->format('F j, Y');
```

Comment: Why would you use a 3rd party library for something that's just as easy and built-in?

Comment: @JonStirling why not? I do not see what OP meant. He can use Carbon from the day one not only for this task but also for other tasks if he has something else. Of course, it he wants to make it simple and quick, he can go with date-strtotime or DateTime.